# Trying to get data off an original iPhone

Tags: usb, iphone

Yes, I have an *iPhone 1* (3G or whatever it should be called) :)
I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 running in Virtualbox.

I have tried running iTunes under wine, but iTunes doesn't detect a device.

Various articles (see end*) suggest `libimobiledevice`, `fuse`, `libmuxd`, etc.

I get the following:

```
~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ac:1292 Apple, Inc. iPhone 3G
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
$ dmesg | grep -i iphone
[  136.336274] usb 1-2: Product: iPhone
[ 1260.165423] usb 1-2: Product: iPhone
```

```
$ sudo idevicepair pair
[sudo] password for alan: 
No device found, is it plugged in?
```

```
$ sudo ifuse /media/iphone
No device found, is it connected?
If it is make sure that your user has permissions to access the raw usb device.
If you're still having issues try unplugging the device and reconnecting it.
```

I have tried unplug/replug.  I have tried rebooting the computer.
Same result.

`ifuse` has an option `-u, --udid UDID       mount specific device by UDID`
However, in theiPhone, `Settings > General > About` only shows `IMEI` and `ICCID`.

Any suggestions much appreciated. Thank you.

*
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1422940/how-do-i-mount-an-iphone-on-ubuntu-22-04

https://opensource.com/article/21/8/libimobiledevice-iphone-linux

https://www.maketecheasier.com/easily-mount-your-iphone-as-an-external-drive-in-ubuntu/

https://www.bollyinside.com/articles/how-to-use-an-iphone-with-linux/

https://cellularnews.com/mobile-phone/how-to-use-iphone-with-linux-complete-guide/

Comment: Did you create a mount point like /media/iphone. that does not exist unless you create it in advance. Older post. I have not had to use ppa ( as shown) to install any of the drivers with newer versions of Ubuntu. https://askubuntu.com/questions/909988/i-connect-my-iphone-5-ios-10-3-1-but-my-ubuntu-16-04-doesnt-seem-to-detect-it/910094#910094

Comment: If all you want to do is get the info off the iphone, why are you using Linux? Why not just access it through Windows or MacOS?

Comment: @oldfred, yes `/mount/iphone`. Thank you for the link: I'll try that. Maybe the driver is so old it's been removed. @Bib, I did try iTunes under Windows7 (in Virtualbox), but iTunes showed nothing in its Devices list. (I forgot about Ask Ubuntu - maybe should have posted there).